# Running more than one command with xargs

Tags: xargs, exec

Is it possible to use find + xargs in order to invoke more than one command? I am trying to find all files whose size is greater than 100 chars. and less than 1000 chars , change their permissions and print list of files into file. I can do it with exec e.g

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -size +100c -size -1000c -exec chmod a+r {} \; -print > testfile
```

But is there any way how to achieve this with xargs?

```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -size +100c -size -1000c -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' chmod a+r '{}' -print >testfile
```

the last print won't execute or throws error. Is there a way to achieve it with xargs?

Comment: you could insert a `tee` between the commands like `find|tee|xargs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any of the GNUisms here (and you probably want a `-mindepth 1` to exclude `.`), and you don't need to run one `chmod` per file:

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -type l -size +100c -size -1000c -print \
  -exec chmod a+r {} + >testfile
```

(I've also added a `! -type l` because `-size` would check the size of the symlink while `chmod` will change the permissions of the *target* of the symlink so it doesn't make sense to consider symlinks. Chances are you'd want to go further and only consider *regular* files (`-type f`))

That works here because `chmod` doesn't output anything on its stdout (which otherwise would end-up in testfile).

More generally, to avoid that, you'd need to do:

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -type l -size +100c -size -1000c -print -exec sh -c '
  exec cmd-that-may-write-to-stdout "$@" >&3 3>&-' sh {} + 3>&1 > testfile
```

So that `find`'s stdout goes to `testfile` but `cmd-that-may-write-to-stdout`'s stdout goes to the original stdout before redirection (as saved with `3>&1` above).

Note that in your:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -size +100c -size -1000c -exec chmod a+r {} \; -print > testfile
```

`testfile` would contain the files for which `chmod` has succeeded (the `-print` being after `-exec` means `-exec` is another condition for that `-print`, and `-exec` succeeds if the executed command returns with a non-zero exit status).

If you wanted to use `xargs` (here using GNU syntax), you could use `tee` and process substitution:

```
 find . ! -name . -prune ! -type l -size +100c -size -1000c -print0 |
   tee >(tr '\0' '\n' > testfile) |
   xargs -r0 chmod a+r
```

To save the output of `find` with NULs turned into newlines into `testfile`. Note however that that `tr` command is running in background. Your shell will wait for `xargs` (at least, most shells will also wait for `tee` and `find`), but not for `tr`. So there's a little chance that `tr` has finished writing data to `testfile` by the time the shell runs the next command. If it's more important that the `testfile` be fully written by then than all the permissions be modified, you may want to swap the `xargs` and `tr` commands above.

Another options is to wrap the whole code above in:

```
(<that-code>) 3>&1 | cat
```

That way, the shell will wait for `cat` and that `cat` will only exit when all the processes that have that file descriptor 3 open on the writing end of the pipe it reads (which includes `tr`, `find`, `tee`, `xargs`) have exited.

Another option is to use `zsh` globs here:

```
files=(./*(L+100L-1000^@))
chmod a+r $files
print -rl $files > testfile
```

Though you could run into a *too many arguments* errors if the list of files is very big. `find -exec +` and `xargs` work around that by running several `chmod` commands if needed. You can use `zargs` in `zsh` for that.