# xargs running more than one command?

Tags: find, disk-usage, xargs

Is it possible to use `xargs` to run more than one command? The only related information I found [was this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249065/running-more-than-one-command-with-xargs), but the answer was not related to `xargs`.

I'm running a simple

```
du / -ah | sort -r -n | head -n 10 |  awk '{print $2}'
```

to find the files that occupy most disk space. However, it is returning also directories, and I want to delete only *files* in order to keep any structure.

I am weary of using `find` command, because I am not sure if I can search by disk usage, and not file size.

Any input would be super appreciated!

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22432/216907 all you need is `find` to filter only regular files towards `du`.

Comment: Also be sure to `sort` before `head`, like into the [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381391/find-biggest-files-and-delete-automatically) linked to your previous question, in order to get the files you need.

Comment: Are you using GNU/LInux?

Comment: Hello @thanasisp! Thanks for your reply. Yeah, I'm using Debian. You're right about the sort before the head, I don't know what the heck was I thinking, my bad! Thanks for pointing it out. I was gonna be scratching my head for a while there. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, see also linked posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` to get only regular files and run `du` for them. Standard error is supressed for the command below, because if you do it for your root directory, there could be some complaints for some special dirs. Here `-h` is used for both `du` and `sort`, which is good for sorting displaying file sizes.

```
find / -type f -exec du -h {} + 2>/dev/null | sort -hr | head | cut -f2-
```

Also the newline is used as the file separator for the above command. The safe way into a GNU shell is to use the null byte to separate the arguments like:

```
find / -type f -exec du -h0 {} + 2>/dev/null | sort -zhr | head -z | cut -zf2- | xargs -r0 <some command to run for the 10 biggest files>
```

For your case (searching `/` as any user) just print the files, together with their size, and decide what to do. Don't send the result directly to `rm --`.

See also:

- [Getting with du size of files only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22432/getting-size-with-du-of-files-only)
- [Find and delete biggest files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381391/find-biggest-files-and-delete-automatically)

Comment: Thank you again @thanasisp! This is a very concise and straightforward answer, I will definitely look into it and try it out. I've learnt something very important, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*directories* are one of many types of *files* (regular, directory, symlink, fifo, device...). Maybe you meant *regular files* as that's the other type of files beside directories that have disk space allocated for them¹.

```
du / -ah | head -n 10 | sort -r -n | awk '{print $2}'
```

Is wrong because with `-h`, you get KMGT... suffixes which means `sort -n` won't work. The GNU implementation of `sort` has a `-h` option to decode those suffixes but because of rounding, the order may still be wrong.

Also beware that hard links are counted only once and that file paths may contain newline characters and not be made of text. Not to mention that your `awk` returning the second whitespace delimited field will choke on file paths containing whitespace. 0 is the only byte value that can't occur in a file path, so you want to use NUL-delimited records to represent file lists.

`-h` is a GNU extension. The GNU implementation of `find` can report disk usage with `-printf %b` or `-printf %k`, so you could do something like:

```
find . -type f -printf '%b\t%p\0' |
  sort -zrn |
  numfmt -d $'\t' -z --to=iec --from-unit=512 |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

Note that the `tr` is only to output it for human consumption, if you wanted to post-process that list, you'd want to keep the format NUL-delimited. For instance, to delete the 10 largest (in terms of disk usage) files:

```
find . -type f -printf '%b\t%p\0' |
  sort -zrn |
  head -zn10 |
  cut -zf 2- |
  xargs -r0 rm -f
```

(`-printf`, `-z`, `-r`, `-0` are all GNU extensions, though `xargs -0` is now supported by a few other implementations; `-r` as well to a lesser extent).

Technically, `rm` unlinks the files from their parent directory. You might find that that pipeline returns the same file linked to 10 different directories; you'd then unlink it from them, but if that file is still linked to some more directories, you won't reclaim its space.

If you wanted to delete all the entries (links) in the directories under `.` of the  10 largest files, you could do:

```
find . -type f -printf '%b\t%D:%i\t%p\0' |
  sort -zrn |
  gawk -F'\t' -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '!seen[$2]++ && ++n > 10 {exit}1' |
  cut -zf 3- |
  xargs -r0 rm -f
```

---

<sup>¹ beware that for files of type *directory*, `du` reports the disk usage of the directory file itself, plus that of any unique file that it lists and those of its subdirectories recursively.</sup>

Comment: Hello @Stéphane! Thanks a bunch for your reply. It is indeed a very **elegant and precise** way of achieving what I want. I have to reckon, for a rookie like me, it looks a bit daunting, but surely it's food for thought, and hopefully I will understand a bit more the realms of `gawk`.
This reply is indeed extremely complete and detailed. I hope I get to understand it in it's entirety; mostly the gawk part. Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge!